# Serving assets is very slow in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-chrome, asset-pipeline, assets, sprockets

I have a standart rails 3 webapp with the default asset pipeline. All of a sudden, the assets took a very long time to load (my page loads went to ~1-2secs to ~1min). The server response time (/home) is normal, but some .css and .js files are pending for very long (up to 45 seconds). The only few assets that take this long are those provided by gems (eg: `modernizr-rails/vendor/assets/javascripts/modernizr.js`)

For example, for `modernizr.js?body=1` :

Headers:

```
Request URL:http://dev.sharewizz.com:3000/assets/modernizr.js?body=1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
```

Stats:

```
DNS Lookup  5.00 s
Connecting  20.07 s
Sending     0
Waiting     10 ms
Receiving   3 ms
```

It it a problem with sprockets ? How do I know what's wrong ?

Notes: <strike>all other browsers behave the same.</strike> **Edit: Actually the problem is only with chrome**, not even safari.
I've tried to launch my server with rails s on port 3000 and on port 80 (no changes)

If I access `http://localhost:3000/assets/modernizr.js?body=1`, most of the times it is instant, sometimes it wait for very long.

Answer (score 11):

Another option - HDD isn't fast enough for logs, just bump into this (suddenly) on my dev pc. Try to set this into **config/development.rb**:

```
# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = false #true
```

If you have a lot of assets, each one take the time to write into dev log, adding up to several minutes total.

Comment: There is a gem 'quiet-assets' for that.

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue in chrome where the browser tries a dns request and waits for a timeout (you can see in the developer tools / network tab if you hover on the colored timelines, it says waiting (30000ms or higher), receiving (4ms).

In the case you are soing something like this: `127.0.0.1  localhost.mysite.com` in hostfile, and access `http://localhost.mysite.com` in the browser), you might try to just access it with localhost on port 80:

- Start rails with `rvmsudo rails server -p 80`
- Access `http://localhost` in chrome

That might solve the issue.

Comment: This other question may also help some people on OS X >= Lion: http://superuser.com/questions/313128/lion-name-resolution-order

Answer (score 0):

Precompile your assets and enable asset pipelining for development env. This may  however not load the changes that you make in your source code without restarting the server.

Comment: `rake assets:precompile;` then `rails server -e production`. No errors. But I get a 404 not found on application-701b5....js and .css.
`ls public/assets/application` and I see application-701b5....js. The exact same file.

Comment: Had to put `config.serve_static_assets` to `true` in `production.rb`. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736031). Everything is fast in production mode.

Comment: If I switch back to development, it's slow again (pages does not take an extra few seconds, but minutes). I want to develop in development env anyway, so I'm solving this problem.