# javascript_include_tag takes 44 seconds in development in Rails 4.1

Tags: performance, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade, sprockets

I'm using Rubinius 2.2.10 and Rails 4.1.6.

since upgrading from rails 3.2, my development environment takes a very long time to load with sprockets' javascript_include_tag whenever the javascript changes. 44 seconds. (I'm using sprockets-2.11.0)

in my development.rb there is this option:

```
# This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
# number of complex assets.
config.assets.debug = true
```

but even if I set it to false it takes the same amount of time.

There is a fair bit of javascript in the app (bootstrap and datatables), but it never took that long on Rails 3.2. Any Idea why this is happening and how to speed it back up?

here is my full development.rb file -

```
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'environments_module.rb'))
include EnvironmentsModule

Rails.application.configure do #- Registration::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  APP_CONFIG= YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, "config", "calm_app.yml"))

  config.communication_host_url = "http://localhost:3004"

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false


  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true

  #CACHING
  # config.cache_store = :memory_store, { size: 64.megabytes }
  config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, {:pool_size => 5, :compress => true}
  #not specifying a server above, this means memcache server is running on localhost on default port - this may not be ideal see the rails guide
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  ##  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options =  APP_CONFIG['invitation_mailer']['default_url_options']
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  #log ActiveRecord
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) if defined? Rails::Console

  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(mangle: false) # default is `true` in Rails
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
    :email => {
        :email_prefix => "[Exception]",
        :sender_address => %{support@test.com},
        :exception_recipients => %w{calm@test, calmernst@test.com, rya@test.com}
    }

  # auto rotate log files, keep 2 of 3MB each
  config.logger = Logger.new(config.paths['log'].first, 1, 3*1024*1024)
  config.log_level = :debug #:info
  #this is the config for the bullet gem which helps to identify inefficient queries in development
  config.after_initialize do
    Bullet.enable = true
    Bullet.bullet_logger = true # see results in log/bullet.log
  end

end
```

Comment: did you restart your server after changing it from true to false?

Comment: yes, I am pretty sure it takes effect because I get errors when set to false regarding unfindable images.

Comment: seems related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809218/serving-assets-is-very-slow-in-development) except he has troubles only on chrome whereas my issue is with all browsers I've tried (firefox, chromium, safari).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by removing

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(mangle: false) # default is `true` in Rails
```

from config/environments/development.rb

I only need it for production anyway so no reason for it to be in development.rb.